# how can i create a Whatsapp shaped border property in Css?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, border

[this is what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPIkE.png)  I am trying to make a **Glowing WHATS-APP icon**.. and for that i need to make exact shape of icon in border in CSS. But i don't know how to do it.

I have tried following till now.. it works for Face Book, Instagram logos, but doesn't work for Whats-app.
here's HTML for SVG:

```
 <button class="btn">
                    <li class="li3">
                        <a href="http://wa.me/+917226072534" target="_blank">
                            <svg class="svg3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40"
                                fill="currentColor" color="rgb(0, 190, 0)" class="bi bi-whatsapp" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </button>
```

here's my CSS for border:

```
.svg3 {
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: ;
}
```

here's my CSS for hover:

```
.li3 a :hover {
    color: rgb(150, 255, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgb(200, 255, 0, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

edit: plz helpppppp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Instead of a border you could use a [drop-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow())

Comment: If this works for other logos, my guess is the whatsapp logo has a different format / pixel makeup. Can you create a [mre] please?

Comment: You should provide some more code

Comment: Please create an actual [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I just created a codepen [pen](https://codepen.io/njoy78/pen/rNzwJde) where you can see the result(not so beautiful tho)

This is the html:

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

This is the css:

```
div.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #131313;
  border: 1rem solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div.logo::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background: #131313;
  border-left: .9rem solid green;
  border-bottom: .9rem solid green;
  transform: translate(-25%, 25%) skew(-25deg) rotate(-10deg);
}
```

However this is not the best way of doing it, logos are usually svgs or images, designing a logo in pure html and css is not a good practice, if you just want to give the logo a glowing effect you should create a gif (not optimal) or create a svg and then give the style to that svg. There are many ways of building svgs (Canva, for example, do that and you don't have to write all the paths, you just create the project and export it in svg).
Hope it was helpful.

EDIT: i misunderstood and thought you wanted to reproduce the whatsapp logo in html and css, sorry for that(-_-).
If what you want to do is just add a shadow to a square image with a transparent background you can use the css rule:

```
    filter: drop-shadow(/* properties */);
```

to add the shadow only to the content of the image(the logo) and not to whole image

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what i want to do is.. i want to make a border around the bottom left of the logo.  bootstrap logo(whats-app) is square, but i managed to make round borders around it so i can make a hover glow effect.